# Assign Role when user login APIGEE + USERGRID

Tags: apigee, usergrid

I am new in APIGEE + Usergrid , I am using function for user login below

```
client.login(username, password,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          alert('Invalid username or password.');
          $(".ajax_loader").hide();
          $("#login-btn").show();
        } else {
          //login succeeded
          client.getLoggedInUser(function(err, data, user) {
```

and I want to assign permission and Role when user login into Application using script
   My problem is when I assign Role and Permission using dashboard (APIGEE Dashboard) 
   after Signup, Login user able to ADD/EDIT/DELETE, But I want to set Role and Permission
   using script, Please let me know How to assign Role and permission When user login into Application.

Thanks
Vipin S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you would use the assignRole function.  Search for "Usergrid.Entity.prototype.assignRole" in apigee.js for more details.